# 2009 Hyundai Sante Fe - gas smell in cabin after replacing fuel sending unit. has been repaired 4x's now

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, gasoline, smell, santa-fe

Fuel sending unit replaced.  Since then  it has gas smell in car. It has been redone by mechanics four times now but still has a gas smell when the gas level is in the first quarter of the tank.

Cap is on tight.

Why does the gas smell in my car continue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack exchange.  You can take the tour by clicking here.  http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: If you fill up your tank halfway and let the car sit, is there any dripping fuel?  You can place some cardboard or newspaper under the fuel tank and the engine.  If you have a leak and it drips on it, you should see some sort of stain even though the fuel may evaporate quickly.  Have you tried popping the hood and sniffing around in there to see if the odor is stronger.  Any additional information you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I will try this. Just filled tank on way home.  When filling tank I used to hear the tank make 2 knocks just before gas flow stops and it is no longer doing this. I have told this to the mechanics. No gas smell in the engine area just in the cabin and outside of the car. Cabin has the gas smell just with the first 1/4 of the full tank when it gets below that mark I don't smell the gas any more until the next fill up.

Comment: If your parking this in your garage and your water heater is in there, that could be dangerous if you have a gas water heater and there is pilot light.  Interested in your test results.  Good luck.

Comment: Tried the cardboard and no stain.  Gas smell very strong today on way to work and back home and by then gas gauge just past the 1/4 mark from the top and gas smell getting better by the time I got to the mechanics to get oil changed and they said they could not smell the gas but I did drive with the windows down because it was giving me a headache. No, garage does not have hot water heater but thanks for thinking of that. Mechanics don't know what else to do. Getting desperate. Would like to trade in but probably won't get enough money to pay off loan. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @vini_i  Can you take a look at this thread?

Comment: I'd think either the tank is damaged around the sending unit or the seal isn't sealing. IIRC the locking tabs on these can rust and cause fumes to enter the cabin through the rear seat.

Answer (score 1):

I had a 2002 Santa Fe and we were smelling gas whenever we filled up. Tried a new gas cap, checked the lines, nothing.

Eventually we checked the filler neck. On the 2002 there was a cover to 'protect' the filler neck in the wheel well, but dirt could fly up and catch inside the cover. When I removed it, I saw the area where the filler neck was packed with dirt.

The dirt had retained moisture, and rusted out the filler neck. So, when we would fill up gas would soak into the dirt, thus the smell. But the dirt was enough to keep any leaks from dripping to the ground.

I never did get around checking the fuel filter (replaced it with a 2010 Tuscon), but replacing the filler neck solved the gas smell problem for us.