# was anyone successful in getting rid of the gas smell in their 2009 santa fe?

Tags: santa-fe

My 2009 Santa Fe smells like gasoline inside the car and outside the car usually upon filling it up. Once it gets down between 1/2 and 1/4 tank left the smell dissipates some. The mechanic has checked the seals the filler neck? Any other ideas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2009 Hyundai Sante Fe - gas smell in cabin after replacing fuel sending unit. has been repaired 4x's now](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/2009-hyundai-sante-fe-gas-smell-in-cabin-after-replacing-fuel-sending-unit-ha)

Answer (score 1):

Your mechanic needs to do an "Evaporative Emission System" test.  This consists of visual inspection, plus putting pressurized smoke into the fuel system to attempt to find leaks.

Hyundai has a poor history with both EVAP system leaks and failing fuel filler necks (check the post cited above by Enot).

Is the check engine light on?  You should have the system scanned.  I suspect you will have one or more P04xx codes - gross or small evaporative emissions leaks.